# Efficient Matlab way of reducing 2D segments?

Tags: matlab, geometry, 2d, overlap, segment

I need to write a function to simplify a set of segments. In particular:

Given the set of 2D segments (x and y coordinates)

- Keep only one replica in case of overlapping (or almost overlapping) segments
- For each kept part keep count of how many overlaps were present on it.

So the input would be a big set of segments (with many overlaps)
And the output would be non overlapping segments with counts for each one of them.

An example input is shown in this matlab plot
[image: example]

As you can see some lines look thicker cause there are multiple overlaps.
As a result I would need just the skeleton with no overlaps, but I would need the information of the overlaps as a number for each output segment.

I am not an expert working with segments and geometrical problems.
What would be the most efficient way of solving such problem? I am using Matlab, but a code example in any high level language would help. Thanks!

EDIT
As requested here is also a sample dataset, you can get it from this google drive link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r2hkG7gI0qhzfP-Mmn8HzIil1o47Z2nA

The input is a csv with 276 cable segments
The output is a csv with 58 cable segments (the reduced segments) + an extra column containing the number of overlapping cables for each segment kept.

The input could contain many more segments. The idea is that the reduction should eliminate cables that are parallel and overlapping with each other, with a certain tolerance.
For example if 2 cables are parallel but far away they should be kept both.

I don't care about the tolerances it's fine if the output is different, I just need an idea on how to solve this problem efficiently cause the code should run fast even with many many segments as input.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including a simple demonstrative input data set, and your expected output for that data set. The graphical example helps in understanding, but not in answering your question directly. Please also pre-emptively address edge cases - e.g. what happens if segments are collinear but not overlapping? What is the tolerance for "overlapping"? How do you measure that tolerance? What assumptions can you make (e.g. are segments always parallel?) Etc...

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is probably not the most suited language for geometrical manipulation. PostgreSQL/PostGIS would be a better tool, but if you don't have choice here is one solution to get the skeleton of a line:

```
% Random points
P = [0 0; 
1 1; 
2 1; 
1.01 1.02; 
0.01 0.01];
% positive buffer followed by a negative buffer   
pol = polybuffer(polybuffer(P,'lines',0.25,'JointType','miter'),-0.249,'JointType','miter');
plot(P(:,1),P(:,2),'r.','MarkerSize',10)
hold on
plot(pol)
axis equal
% Drop the duplicate with uniquetol (with a tolerance of 0.005) to get the centerline
utol = uniquetol(pol.Vertices,0.005,'ByRows',true) 
hold off; 
plot(utol(:,1),utol(:,2),'b')
```

Result:

[image]

And the center line:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes skeletonization is a fine idea! But how can I get the number of overlaps after skeletonization? Cause I need the number of overlaps for each segment that is kept. You can check the example, I just edited the question.